# data binding does not reflect the change

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have 2 check boxes binded to same source on appSetting.xaml page. When a check box state is changed, state is written back to isolated storage.

The problem is that when a check box is checked or unchecked, second does not reflect the change. But when I navigate to other page and than again to it. Both controls are updated as they are loaded from isolated storage. But I want them to reflect the change immediately if one to them changes it state (binding mode is also set to two way for both of the controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use INotifyPropertyChanged interface
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx